# Will json.dumps(sort_keys=True ..) recursively sort nested dictionaries as well?

Tags: python, json

I need to ensure that the string produced by `json.dumps` does not ever change if dictionary keys are reordered.

From testing, passing `sort_keys=True` does indeed do the trick and it does recursively ensure that fields are sorted.

However the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) are unclear and ambiguous about the recursive nature/behaviour.

> If sort_keys is true (default: False), then the output of dictionaries
> will be sorted by key; this is useful for regression tests to ensure
> that JSON serializations can be compared on a day-to-day basis.

Should I write my own recursive function to dump keys recursively or rely on python to do it.

```
import json
a = {
  "one": "one",
  "nested": {
    "two": "two",
    "three": "three",
    "nested": {
      "four": "four",
      "five": "five"
    }
  }
}
a_str = json.dumps(a, sort_keys=True)
print(a_str)

b = {
  "nested": {    
    "three": "three",
    "two": "two",
    "nested": {      
      "five": "five",
      "four": "four"
    }
  },
  "one": "one"
}
b_str = json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True)
print(b_str)

print(a_str == b_str) # prints true
assert  a_str == b_str

assert a_str != json.dumps(b) # Works as sort_keys is False by default
```

[replit](https://replit.com/@louisnow/TrustworthyCyberExponents#main.py)

Comment: Yes, all nested dictionaries will also have sorted keys.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can rely on that behavior.

In fact, their statement that you quote:

> this is useful for regression tests to ensure that JSON serializations can be compared on a day-to-day basis

would be wrong if `sort_keys` didn't work recursively on nested JSON objects.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is pretty clear if you read it in the sense

> all dictionaries encoded will have their keys sorted

This is also evident from the source for the JSON encoder; `_iterencode_dict` is called for each dictionary encountered (even if returned from e.g. the `default=` callable).

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8e75c6b49b7cb8515b917f01b32ece8c8ea2c0a0/Lib/json/encoder.py#L333-L355

```
def _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level):
    # ...
    if _sort_keys:
        items = sorted(dct.items())
    else:
        items = dct.items()
    # ...
```